# use playwright to test a streamlit edited web page, prompt select element error

Tags: drop-down-menu, playwright

The test page is written in streamlit:
example code:

```
import streamlit as st
st.selectbox('select pypi:', ['a', 'b', 'c'], 0)
```

use playwright to select the element
example code:

```
from playwright.sync_api import Playwright, sync_playwright, expect

def run(playwright: Playwright) -> None:
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    context = browser.new_context()
    page = context.new_page()
    page.goto("http://localhost:8501/")
    page.wait_for_timeout(1000)
    page.locator('//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/section/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]').select_option('a')
    page.wait_for_timeout(1000)

    # ---------------------
    context.close()
    browser.close()

with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    run(playwright)
```

How to succinctly select elements from a selectbox written by streamlit using a playwright? Show me your code.

Comment: What's the problem with the current code? Almost always, avoid those [long chains of hardcoded selectors](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#misusing-developer-tools-generated-selectors). They're unreliable.

Comment: Thank you. Problem solved.Streamlit selectbox component has an input property that you can simply fill in.Example:page.locator('//input[contains(@aria-label, "user")]').fill("btp")

Comment: Nice find. Please add a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).